# iphone crash reporter

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to access the crash log over the application? The last.fm client showed me today a "we found a crash log" altert with the option to send it, so I think it must be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the description of the solution I found: [Crash Reporter for iPhone Applications](http://www.restoroot.com/Blog/2008/10/18/crash-reporter-for-iphone-applications/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although you probably won't get much out of them if you don't have the dSYM file and source code:

> After you've synced with iTunes the
>   crash logs should be in one of the
>   following folders:
>
> On Mac OS X they are located in
>   ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice.
>
> Windows XP: C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Application Data\Apple
>   computer\Logs\CrashReporter/
>
> Windows Vista:
>   C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Apple
>   computer\Logs\CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

(This from the [help page](http://www.yummyapp.com/2008/09/help.html) for my application.)

Answer (score 0):

@stephen I think the poster was asking about an iPhone app finding a crash log without access to a Mac/PC…

And I think the answer is - this was possible on 2.0 - but Apple clamped down on 2.1 and now prevent your app from accessing the logs. :-(

Comment: To be fair, they were preventing you from reading any files outside your sandbox, not just the logs.